# woocommerce add additional fields which will update price as well

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have attached a screenshot. please have a look.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1RMI.jpg)

If you have viewed the screenshot there is a book now button, Above that button, I want a select list something like this-
Flight:
option 1 : $15,
option 2 : $30

If I select any one of them it will update price as well as it will also update in the cart too.

[This is the reference link](http://voetbaltrips.com/manchester-city-watford-14-december.html). I want something like the reference link.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

For the easiest way you can use this plugin: [Plugin Link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/yith-woocommerce-product-add-ons/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Let me check whether it is working for me or not.